# About using the term "similarly" in proofs

Tags: soft-question, proof-writing

It has been argued that using the term "similarly" in proofs to avoid repetition of similar parts of a proof is considered as a non-professional way of constructing a proof.

Is it considered as a sneaky way for one to avoid showing a lack of knowledge to construct the rest of the proof? Or is it acceptable for students to do this in exams as long as the rest of the proof is fairly obvious? Or is it even a subjective matter?

I haven't found another question on here discussing this and it is something that always comes up to my mind, especially during exams at which time might be limited.

(I'm not sure if this is too broad or if it should have been asked on Academia instead.)

Comment: I use this term only if a similar proof has already been given. This avoids repetition.

Comment: When writing a paper, that depends on your level and the readers level. In an exam, the regulations of the institute apply, so you might want to ask there.

Comment: I think the standard for the usage should be something along the lines of "the argument or calculation cited goes through for the present problem with only minor changes".  As with any instance of omitted details, there's a range...people differ in what they'd agree were "minor changes" and, of course, it's harder to spot error in omitted work.  Certainly, when I am checking a paper that I expect might be flawed, I first look at places where the author has written "clearly" or "obviously" or, as you suggest, "similarly".

Comment: Don't forget the word "analogously", as in "The proof for the other case follows analogously".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are asking for an opinion. For a proof which is formally specified in a precise language which can be checked mechanially, the situation does not arise. For proofs written in human language and written for human readers, what constitutes a complete proof is a matter of opinion because they are really proof sketches with more or less details.